Should "with" and "without" be capitalized in a paper title or not?
I've seen the discussion about minor and major words in titles, but the words "with" and "without" are not mentioned there. Should they be capitalized or not, in titles?

The words 'with' and 'without' are prepositions. One answer mentions "preposition of more than three characters" and another has "one and two-letter words are not capitalized, so a preposition like 'at' is not capitalized, but 'about' or 'under' would be".

British English and American English tend to differ on this point.

This is probably no more than a matter of style: You pays your money and you takes your choice. The nature of the title and  position of the word will also have an influence, e,g, "The World without You" "The World Without" - "Who Were You With?" "Dealing with Imaginary Numbers".

I take it by "a paper" you mean an essay you've written for a class at school.  If so, and if your teacher is concerned with such things, you could ask what style manual to use.  Choice of style manual often varies by discipline.

As Weather Vane pointed out, "with" and "without" are already in the scope of the original question, and are covered in some of the answers, as prepositions. This is a duplicate of the original question, or a comment on its existing answers.
